# Iterating over module exports with implicit any

Tags: angularjs, typescript

So I'm writing a module with sub-modules for angular. Notation:

```
module App.services {
    export class SomeService { }
}
```

and I initialize all services using:

```
function defToArray(def: any): any[] {
    return (def.dependencies || []).concat(def)
}

for (var s in App.services)
    app.service(s, defToArray(App.services[s]));
```

However `defToArray(App.services[s])` causes "Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type".

I already tried casting like `defToArray(<any>App.services[s])` and `defToArray(App.services[s] as any)`, but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casts are not very tightly binding.

Instead of

```
defToArray(<any>App.services[s])
```

try

```
defToArray((<any>App.services)[s])
```

or if you prefer

```
defToArray((<{[key:string]:any}>App.services)[s])
```

For clarification, the goal here is not to cast the type of `App.services[s]`, you're actually trying to provide type information for the access-by-index operator. This is only an issue when `noImplicitAny` is enabled (but IMO it always should be, so it's just one of the things you learn to adjust to)

Comment: You're a life saver!

Comment: @Ken glad to help, I added some more info for context in case you were curious.